# Replace existing worksheets with external files

Tags: excel, vba

I found this VBA code online to pull data from multiple external Excel workbooks into a single workbook, each on its own new worksheet.

Instead, I need to replace the existing worksheets which are labeled "QDS", "QDS (2)", "QDS (3)", and so on up til "QDS (23)" (just not replace the first worksheet, which is where all my formulas are).

```
Sub MergeExcelFiles()
   Dim fnameList, fnameCurFile As Variant
   Dim countFiles, countSheets As Integer
   Dim wksCurSheet As Worksheet
   Dim wbkCurBook, wbkSrcBook As Workbook

   fnameList = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Microsoft Excel Workbooks (*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm),*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm", Title:="Choose Excel files to merge", MultiSelect:=True)

   If (vbBoolean <> VarType(fnameList)) Then

       If (UBound(fnameList) > 0) Then
           countFiles = 0
           countSheets = 0

           Application.ScreenUpdating = False
           Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

           Set wbkCurBook = ActiveWorkbook

           For Each fnameCurFile In fnameList
               countFiles = countFiles + 1

               Set wbkSrcBook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=fnameCurFile)

               For Each wksCurSheet In wbkSrcBook.Sheets
                   countSheets = countSheets + 1
                   wksCurSheet.Copy after:=wbkCurBook.Sheets(wbkCurBook.Sheets.Count)
               Next

               wbkSrcBook.Close SaveChanges:=False

           Next

           Application.ScreenUpdating = True
           Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

           MsgBox "Processed " & countFiles & " files" & vbCrLf & "Merged " & countSheets & " worksheets", Title:="Merge Excel files"
       End If

   Else
       MsgBox "No files selected", Title:="Merge Excel files"
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: So at the beginning of the process there are 24 sheets in your "master" workbook (formula sheet plus QDS to QDS(23))? Should all of the QDS sheets first be deleted before running any import? Do imported sheets need to be renamed?  It's not too clear what your exact desired end-point is.

Comment: What goes where? This is not clear

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  What have you tried so far? And are you having any specific problems that you think you should understand, but cannot figure out? This forum has a strong "work on it and ask when you get stuck" culture. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to get a feel for this.

Comment: @TimWilliams The QDS sheets should NOT first be deleted before running any import - they are currently blank, and I'd like the external sheets being imported to immediately replace the existing sheets and keep the same sheet names. Otherwise, I'm finding that if I delete the existing sheets and then import external sheets, all of my formulas with external references to those sheets are automatically deleted. I hope this makes sense - I'm inexperienced & have difficulty even explaining my process. Sorry, I'm really trying! I work for a non-profit & am working on our data collection processes.

Comment: @TimWilliams you're my hero!!!! That worked perfectly - I can't thank you enough!!!!! Much appreciation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try something like this:

```
Dim done As Boolean
'....
'....
For Each fnameCurFile In fnameList
    countFiles = countFiles + 1

    Set wbkSrcBook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=fnameCurFile)

    For Each wksCurSheet In wbkSrcBook.Sheets
        countSheets = countSheets + 1
        'check have somewhere to paste the content...
        If countSheets > 23 Then
            MsgBox "Reached max. sheet count of 23!", vbExclamation
            done = True
            Exit For
        End If
        'copy the sheet content, not the actual sheet....
        '   skip the formulas sheet
        wksCurSheet.UsedRange.Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets(countSheets + 1).Range("A1")
    Next

    wbkSrcBook.Close SaveChanges:=False
    If done Then Exit For
Next
'....
'....
```